# Shortest way of testing logical and condition here

Tags: linux, shell, testing, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have this function that checks for the presence of a file pattern

```
trackid=$1
tg=$2
srch=delta-revnue-$trackid
srch2=delta-full-$trackid
testpath() {
var=1
if test -n "$(find $tg -maxdepth 1 -iname "$srch*" -print -quit)"
then

export var=0

else


export var=1

fi

return $var

}

testpath $1 $2
echo "exit code is $?"
```

I want to do condition like

```
 If testpath val1 path =!0  ||  testpath val2 path =1
    echo "some files are missing" 
    else
    stuff  here
    fi
```

I am aware there are N way to do this simple thing. But there was a really short and sweet way of saying this that sounded like ( condition || condition  ) something like that.
How do you say this most succinctly in shell

Answer should be logical && not ||. || will test for only 1 condition and if true it will not look at the other one.

```
testpath var path && testpath var1 path
```

Answer (score 2):

All you would do is this:

```
if testpath val1 path && testpath val2 path
then
  stuff  here
else
  echo "some files are missing"
fi
```

If you really want to switch the order of what is inside the if/else, you could do:

```
testpath val1 path && testpath val2 path

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
  echo "some files are missing"
else
  stuff  here
fi
```

Or somewhat less clearly (using [DeMorgans Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
if ! testpath val1 path || ! testpath val2 path
then
  echo "some files are missing"
else
  stuff  here
fi
```

Also your `testpath` function can be significantly shortened. All you really need is this (I have used the function arguments as per how you want to use the function here):

```
testpath() {
  test -n "$(find "$2" -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$1*" -print -quit)"
}
```

Comment: `if testpath val1 path ||  testpath val2 path` will test for the truth right . I want to do opp. If NOT those conditions then echo "missing" else <stuff to ct running the shell>

Comment: I see, I think the simplest thing to do is just to swap what is inside the if/else part (updated)? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to test the opp condition in the If part . Because the Else part is the actual program and v lengthy . thats why I am setting those flags in the function

Comment: mind you the NOT test for this ` test -n "$(find "$2" -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$1*" -print -quit)"` is dicy because even if the pattern is not found there is a number. that is why I made the function and custom  flags. I guess I will switch the flags opp

Comment: Ok, I see, updated. The result of the `test` shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: It should be && not || I updated in Q. THanks for the simple format. I was getting clouded by too many such formats around